# Using Rolle's Theorem and MVT for twice differentiable functions

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a function that is twice differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. Given that $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$, prove that there exists a $c \in(0,1)$ such that $|f''(c)|\geq 4|f(1)-f(0)|$ .

Yes, I know that many questions are already posted about this problem, but do hear me out.

Many other theorems use Definite  Integrals; however, I need to do this question using only Rolle's Theorem and the Mean Value Theorem.

My understanding so far:

1. Use MVT to get $f'(c_0)=f(1)-f(0)$
2. Use Rolle's theorem to get $f''(c_1)=0.$ Since $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$

I would sincerely appreciate it if you guys could help me with this question and not close it because it is a duplicate.
Thank you, Sirs and Madames.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(0) = f(1)$ the result is obvious, otherwise we can (by scaling and translating $f$ if necessary) assume wlog that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, so that we need to prove $\vert f''(c) \vert \geq 4$ for some $c \in (0,1)$.

Assume towards a contradiction that for all $x \in (0, 1)$ we have $\vert f''(x)\vert  < 4$,

then the MVT gives us

$$f'(x) = f'(x) - f'(0) < 4x.$$

If we consider the function

\begin{alignedat}{2}
g : \mathbb{R} &\to \mathbb{R}\\ 
  x  &\mapsto f(x) - 2x^2,
\end{alignedat}

for all $x \in (0, 1)$ we get

$$ g'(x) = f'(x) - 4x <0$$

so $g$ is decreasing on $[0, 1]$ and therefore

\begin{alignedat}{2}
 0 = g(0) &> g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\\
\implies f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) &< \frac{1}{2}.
\end{alignedat}

Finally consider the function

\begin{alignedat}{2}
h : \mathbb{R} &\to \mathbb{R}\\ 
  x  &\mapsto 1 - f(1-x),
\end{alignedat}

which has many of the same properties as $f$:

$$
h(0) = 0,\\ 
h(1) = 1,\\
h'(0) = h'(1) = 0,\\
$$

and for all $x \in (0, 1)$ we still have

$$\vert h''(x) \vert = \vert -f''(1-x)\vert <4.$$

Therefore just like before we get

\begin{alignedat}{2}
&&h\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) &< \frac{1}{2}\\
&\implies 
&1 - f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) &< \frac{1}{2}\\
&\implies 
&f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) &> \frac{1}{2},
\end{alignedat}

which is a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand your explanation, is there a way to prove without contradiction?

Comment: @SharminAeheli I don't know, probably. But if you have specific questions regarding this proof, feel free to ask and I will try to clarify.

Comment: Alright, what's the reasoning behind wanting to go and define your own functions?

Comment: @SharminAeheli You don't have to define new functions for it, but the idea is just that (using our assumptions on $f$) we can get from $f''(x) < 4$ to $f'(x) < 4x$ to $f(x)  < 2x^2$ (either by integrating from $0$ to $x$, which you wanted to avoid, or by using the MVT and a monotonicity argument on an auxiliary function). Now we have an upper bound for any function that satisfies our assumptions ($f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, f'(0) = f'(1) = 0, f''(x) < 4$). If we had a function that also satisfies them which is large when $f$ is small and (vice versa) would give us a contradiction, $1-f(1-x)$ works.